# How to Change JFrame Size dynamically

Tags: java, swing, size, jframe

I have a simple drawing program, I set my Jframe's size with the following code:

```
    frame.setSize(900, 700);
```

However, when user change the size of the window, white area to draw, still remain same size therefore, user is not able to draw eventhough he enlarge the window.

http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/31180-java-mini-paint-program.html this is where I start from. I extended class "PadDraw" and wrote most of my code to there, in my other java file, I only create a frame, then I create "PadDraw" object, I crated a container and then added object to the frame's container: content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);

I changed my code:

```
public class PadDraw extends JComponent implements ActionListener, ItemListener, ComponentListener{
    public synchronized void addComponentListener(ComponentListener l) {};
```

.
.
.
.

And I added unimplemented methods, and the "componentResized" is:

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Changed ????");

}
```

But when I changed the window's size, nothing happens.

One thougt: When I added componentlistener to my other file instead of drawPad, componentResized method flags, but because I have created drawPad object before this event occured, I can't change the size =/

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a `LayoutManager` to lay out your components?

Comment: I draw by using Graphics2D,

No I dont use LayoutManager

Comment: so you override the paint() method?

Comment: I draw lines and etc, and call repaint() function

Comment: Again, there's not nearly enough information to guess what you're doing wrong. I suggest that you create a very small separate program, a GUI, and try to add a ComponentListener to a JPanel just to see if you can get it to work. If it works, great, use this code in your main program, but if it still doesn't work, then post your small compilable and runnable program here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you're not drawing directly on the `JFrame` but rather in a `JPanel` or `JComponent` that's been added to the `JFrame`'s contentPane. If it has been added `BorderLayout.CENTER`, then it should expand and contract as the `JFrame` expands and contracts. Things get a little trickier if you're drawing on a `BufferedImage` as you'll have to use a `ComponentListener` to see when the component that holds the `BufferedImage` changes size, and when it does, change the size of the `BufferedImage` without losing the drawing that's already there.

If this answer is not helpful enough, consider giving us more specific information about your current problem and your current program.

In the program that you link to, you're drawing on an Image object whose size is set the first time paint is called. What you'll want to do is to add a `ComponentListener` to the PadDraw object in its own constructer, and in the `ComponentListener`'s `componentResized` method, resize your image using the `PadDraw`'s new height and width. I would only do this however if the new size is larger than the old size. You would also then want to redraw the old image on the new before setting the image variable = to the new image. Then call repaint.

Comment: http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/31180-java-mini-paint-program.html this is where I start from. I extended class "PadDraw" and wrote most of my code to there, in my other java file, I only create a frame, then I create "PadDraw" object, I crated a container and then  added object to the frame's container: content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: How should I add the componentListener to the PadDraw object, I crated JFrame in other file ?

Comment: The ComponentListener should be added to PadDraw in PadDraw's own constructor.

Comment: Ok I added "implements ComponentListener" and added unimplemented methods, in method, "componentResized" I wrote something to understand whether it is called or not. But when I execute my program and change the size of the window "componentResized" will not be called.

Comment: @CanCeylan: And we're supposed to guess what you're doing wrong how? You've got to edit your original post and show code.